# Test::File::Find::Rule check that all our perl scripts have use strict

Tags: perl, testing, cpan

```
use warnings;
use Test::More;
use File::Find::Rule;
use Test::File::Find::Rule;

my $rule = File::Find::Rule->file->name('*.pl')->not_grep(qr/^\s*use\s+strict;/m, sub { 1 });
match_rule_no_result($rule, ".", 'use strict usage');
done_testing();
```

and the output was :

```
out put :
ok 1 - use strict usage
1..1
```

it is always passing the test even when my script doesn't use strict, just like this script which is located inside "." directory.
the same code is available as an example at http://metacpan.org/pod/Test::File::Find::Rule

any clue ?

F.

Comment: Your test will fail if any of your modules use Moose, which enables strictures automatically (or if you use any number of other modules which do the same, or create your own Toolset).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check for `use strict` just do this:

```
my $rule = File::Find::Rule
    ->file->name('*.pl')
    ->not_grep( qr/^\s*use\s+strict;/ )
;
```

**Update**

I agree with Schwern and jrockway: there's a better module for enforcing `use strict`.

That said, here's what I was able to figure out about the particulars of your question.

The `use strict` example provided by [Test::File::Find::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test::File::Find::Rule) is misguided.

As I understand it, the `grep` method in [File::Find::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Find::Rule) will evaluate each line of a file, using each specifier provided, stopping (i.e., retaining the file in its result set) on the first true evaluation. `File::Find::Rule` provides an example of making sure every file **begins** with a shebang line. If the first line fails the regex, the next specifier (the anonymous subroutine) will always return true and the non-conforming file will be found.

```
$rule->grep( qr/^#!.*\bperl/, [ sub { 1 } ] );
```

For a `use strict` test, however, you don't want to restrict yourself to the first line. Also, the `not_grep` method makes the additional specifiers unnecessary: we will retain the file if none of the lines in the file match the regex. Hope that helps.

Comment: I don't think this should be the accepted answer, but it is technically correct, so I gave it +1.  But Schwern's idea is better :)

Answer (score 10):

Consider using [Perl::Critic](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Perl::Critic) instead, which can do this more reliably, is configurable, and do a whole lot more.  There is even [Test::Perl::Critic](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test::Perl::Critic) to enforce it.

Perl::Critic also has the advantage of being aware of things like [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose) which turn on strictures.

Comment: +1.  This is the right answer.  Don't write this yourself when something else already handles the corner cases that you haven't even though of yet.